# How can i getting Class<T> classType = T.class;

Tags: java, android

```
public interface CallBack<T> {
    void onComplete(boolean IsSuccess, T response);
}
```

```
public class Response {
    public Boolean IsSuccess;
    public Object Data;
    public String Message;
}
```

### Actually, Here how i use Example.Request

```
Example.Request(new CallBack<Response>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(boolean IsSuccess, Response response) {
        
    }
});
```

## I want to getting parameterized type from 'T of CallBack'

```
public class Example {

    public static <T> void Request(CallBack<T> callBack) {
        // This line is not correct, but I want like -> T.class
        // Here I want to like 'Response.class'
        Class<T> classType = T.class;
    }
}
```

#### I dont want to pass 'Class.class' like this to Request method

```
public class Example {


    public static <T> void Request(CallBack<T> callBack, Class<T> classType) {

    }
}
```

Message: I want to avoid passing Response.class into the Example.Request() method, Through T of CallBack I wish to get Response.class inside the Request method.
This means if this is possible then I don't need to pass an extra parameter into the Request() method.

### Thanks

Comment: I believe T.class is not available at runtime because of type erasuer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Solution

Here i don't need to pass classType

```
public static <T> void Request(CallBack<T> callBack) {
    // Obtain the actual type arguments of the CallBack parameter
    Type[] actualTypeArguments = ((ParameterizedType) callBack.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments();

    // Obtain the class object of T by casting the first element of the actualTypeArguments array to Class
    Class<T> type = (Class<T>) actualTypeArguments[0];
}
```

Comment: Not ideal. This can be broken in many ways.

Comment: @shmosel ok, Do you want to suggest something?

Comment: Sometimes you need to do what you don't want to do.

Comment: @shmosel means this is not a correct approach.

Comment: That's a judgement call. It's a hack that will work in specific circumstances, but not something I would want to get too reliant on.